# How to convert int to byte[]?

Tags: java, arrays, int, type-conversion, bytebuffer

I tried to convert `int` to `byte[]` and wrote for this following:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
buff.putInt(1222);
buff.get(bytes);
```

but as result I had java.nio.BufferOverflowException without detail message.

As for me code is valid. What is wrong? How to convert `int` to `byte[]`?

Comment: At which line do you get the error?

Comment: buff.get(bytes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to `flip()` your buffer after putting data in.

After you've put the `int` in the buffer, the position is at the end of the buffer. Trying to read data results in `BufferUnderflowException` (not overflow) since there are no bytes left to read in the buffer.

Answer (score 6):

A similar answer which doesn't require calling flip().

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putInt(0x12345678);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

prints http://ideone.com/Ab4Z4V

```
[18, 52, 86, 120]
```

This is 0x12, 0x34, 0x56 and 0x78

Answer (score 3):

This is my approach to achieve it:

```
public static byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
    if ((value >>> 24) > 0) {
        return new byte[]{
            (byte) (value >>> 24),
            (byte) (value >>> 16),
            (byte) (value >>> 8),
            (byte) value
        };
    } else if ((value >> 16) > 0) {
        return new byte[]{
            (byte) (value >>> 16),
            (byte) (value >>> 8),
            (byte) value
        };
    } else if ((value >> 8) > 0) {
        return new byte[]{
            (byte) (value >>> 8),
            (byte) value
        };
    } else {
        return new byte[]{
            (byte) value
        };
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, that this approach **only use the number of bytes required** to represent the number, that means if the number is small use less bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to your own solution but a bit more concise, the result is directly in the byte array.

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    // BigEndian
    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putInt(1222);
    // LittleEndian
    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(1222);
```